# Swap values "true" and "false" via ctrl+a, ctrl+x

Tags: key-bindings

I think it would be useful to have possibility to swap `true` and `false` values in the code rapidly, with combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. Is there some plugin for that or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a plugin ([toggle-bool](https://github.com/sagarrakshe/toggle-bool)) to toggle the boolean values you can try it. It supports the following boolean values:

- `true` <-> `false`
- `yes` <-> `no`
- `on` <-> `off`
- `0` <-> `1`

Comment: Oh, It's what I was looking for. But I have a small problem. Can you fix it? https://github.com/sagarrakshe/toggle-bool/issues/1

Comment: @lucidbrot corrected

Answer (score 13):

There is [switch.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/switch.vim), and it's customizable.

> The main entry point of the plugin is a single command, `:Switch`. When the command is executed, the plugin looks for one of a few specific patterns under the cursor and performs a substition depending on the pattern.

For example if the cursor is on the `true` in the following code:

```
flag = true
```

then upon executing `:Switch`, the `true` will turn into `false`.

Comment: You're welcome! I have this crazy idea of a 'vim-dwim' plugin that acts differently based on syntax under cursor (e.g. when hitting Enter), and I think I'll heavily inspire myself from this plugin. If I ever get to start making it, that is.

Answer (score 11):

## Plethora of Plugins

Toggling `true`/`false` and similar has been implemented by many plugin authors. Two of them have already been mentioned:

- *switch.vim* by Andrew Radev ([#4172](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4172), [github](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/switch.vim))  and
- *toggle-bool* by Sagar Rakshe ([github](https://github.com/sagarrakshe/toggle-bool)).

Others are *toggle* by Timo Teifel ([#895](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=895)), *monday* by Stefan Karlsson ([#1046](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1046)), *toggle_words* by Vincent Wang ([#1676](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1676)), *toggle_word* by Alexandru Ungur ([#1748](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1748)), *incbool.vim* by Dmitry Petrov ([#4361](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4361), [github](https://github.com/can3p/incbool.vim)), *nextval* by Michael Arlt ([#4536](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4536), [github](https://github.com/qwertologe/nextval.vim)).

Just in case you want to increase numbers according to a custom series, e.g. the Fibonacci series, check out *nexus* by Barry Arthur ([github](https://github.com/dahu/Nexus)).

#### Plugins Supercharging `Ctrl-A/X`

However, not all of them follow by default the idea to extend `Ctrl-A/X` but define a new command and/or a new mapping (incl. *switch.vim* and *toggle-bool*). I want to highlight those plugins which 'supercharge' `Ctrl-A/X` out of the box and, therefore, provide by default what the OP has asked:

- **SwapIt** by Michael Brown ([#2294](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2294), [github](https://github.com/mjbrownie/swapit)),
- **Increment-activator** by Takuya Nishigori ([#4817](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4817), [github](https://github.com/nishigori/increment-activator)),
- **CtrlXA** by Konfekt ([#5600](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5600), [github](https://github.com/Konfekt/vim-CtrlXA)),
- **Cycle** by Zef Houssney ([github](https://github.com/zef/vim-cycle)),
- **Cycle** by bootleq ([github](https://github.com/bootleq/vim-cycle))

A related plugin which also extends `Ctrl-A/X` is *speeddating* by Tim Pope ([#2120](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2120), [github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-speeddating)) which allows you to increment dates.

#### Fallback

Some plugins allow to combine a second `Ctrl-A/X` incrementor plugin as a fallback, e.g.

- *SwapIt* by Michael Brown:

  ```
  nmap <Plug>SwapItFallbackIncrement <Plug>SpeedDatingUp
  nmap <Plug>SwapItFallbackDecrement <Plug>SpeedDatingDown
  vmap <Plug>SwapItFallbackIncrement <Plug>SpeedDatingUp
  vmap <Plug>SwapItFallbackDecrement <Plug>SpeedDatingDown
  ```
- *cycle* by bootleq:

  ```
  map <silent> <Plug>CycleFallbackNext <Plug>SpeedDatingUp
  map <silent> <Plug>CycleFallbackPrev <Plug>SpeedDatingDown
  ```
- *switch.vim* by Andrew Radev:

  ```
  nnoremap <c-a> :if !switch#Switch()<bar>call speeddating#increment()<bar>endif<cr>
  nnoremap <c-x> :if !switch#Switch({'reverse': 1})<bar>call speeddating#decrement()<bar>endif<cr>
  ```

Note
If you use the seek behavior of the builtin `Ctrl-A/X` (find next possible value in line to increment), supercharging them can interfere.

Answer (score 2):

change the mapping to what you want to use

the undo is in case you use it on top of a space, since ciw will edit the space instead of the word (and there's no easy way to get to the right word reliably)

```
function SwapBool ()
  let s:w = expand("<cword>")
  if s:w == "false"
    normal ciwtrue
    if expand("<cword>") != "true"
      normal u
    endif
  elseif s:w == "true"
    normal ciwfalse
    if expand("<cword>") != "false"
      normal u
    endif
  endif
endfunction
noremap <C-F> :call SwapBool()^M
```

also note the ^M needs to be `<C-V><Enter>`, not literally ^M

Comment: Welcome to this site! Note that it would be interesting to add a condition which would make the function like the built-in `<C-a>` and `<C-x>` when the current word is not a boolean, this way OP would really be able to use these mappings. Also you can use `<CR>` instead of `^M` in your mapping, and it is usually a best practice to provide a mode to your `map` command, here `nnoremap` would be more appropriate than `noremap`.